# Leaflet small divIcons less than 14px do not align at center of point

Tags: leaflet

I want to add some very small custom [divIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) markers to a Leaflet (v1.9.3) map. However, it seems icons smaller than `[14,14]` do not align at the center of the marker. Following image shows three markers at same location with a circle SVG as the `divIcon` and radii of 50,20,6. Notice the first two center but the 6px one is off center:

[image]

Some control can be had with `iconAnchor` but seems the value would need to vary depending on `iconSize` and the computation isn't obvious to me. Is there a better way to center align small divIcons like above?

Code for above image:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
      #map { height: 100vh; }
    </style>
    <script>
      var map;
      var myIcon = (color = 'red', b = 24) => `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ${b} ${b}">
    <circle fill="${color}" cx="${b/2}" cy="${b/2}" r="${b/2}" />
  </svg>`;
      function init() {
        var map = L.map('map').setView([50.0, 0.0], 13);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);
        var marker = L.marker(
          [51.5, -0.09], {
          icon: L.divIcon({
            html: myIcon('red', 50),
            iconSize: [50,50],
            className: ''
          }),
        }).addTo(map);
        var marker = L.marker(
          [51.5, -0.09], {
          icon: L.divIcon({
            html: myIcon('green', 20),
            iconSize: [20,20],
            className: ''
          }),
        }).addTo(map);
        var marker = L.marker(
          [51.5, -0.09], {
          icon: L.divIcon({
            html: myIcon('blue', 6),
            iconSize: [6,6],
            className: ''
          }),
        }).addTo(map);
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='init();'>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: set `style="display: block"` on the `<svg>` element. `<svg>` elements are use `display: inline` by default which uses some flow layouting algorithm.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6 6" style="display: block">
    <circle fill="blue" cx="3" cy="3" r="3"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice thanks! That kind of makes sense. Still wondering why it only triggers for small icons.